# Question about the sum of subspaces of a vector space $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The following is from my textbook:

Let $S$ and $T$ be subspaces of $V$. The sum $S + T$ is defined by
$$
S + T = \{u + v \mid u \in S, v \in T \}
$$

More generally, the sum of any collection $\{S_{i} \mid i \in K \}$ of subspaces is the set of all finite sums of vectors from the union $\bigcup_i S_{i}$:
$$
\sum_{i \in K} S_{i} = \biggl\{s_{1} + \cdots + s_{n} \biggm\vert s_{j} \in \bigcup_{i \in K} S_{i} \biggr\}
$$

It is not hard to show that the sum of any collection of subspaces of $V$ is a subspace of $V$ and that the sum is the least upper bound under set inclusion:
$$
S + T = \operatorname{lub}\{S, T\}
$$

More generally,
$$
\sum_{i \in K} S_{i} = \operatorname{lub} \{S_{i} \mid i \in K \}
$$

Why is it that we have $s_{j} \in \bigcup_{i \in K} S_{i}$ in the definition of the sum of subspaces instead of $s_{i} \in S_{i}$ as shown in
$$
\sum_{i \in K} S_{i} = \biggl\{s_{1} + \cdots + s_{n} \biggm\vert s_{j} \in \bigcup_{i \in K} S_{i} \biggr\}.
$$

Comment: It is more convenient in case of an infinite family of vector spaces

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace: what exactly is meant by an infinite family of vector spaces?

Comment: $K$ is an arbitrary index set (possibly infinite as noted), it need not contain numbers like $1,\ldots,n$. However, do you see how by grouping terms you could index vectors in a sum using elements of $K$, so the two definitions are equivalent?

Comment: @blargoner: I think I kind of see it, but is it possible to show an example of such a grouping?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment: $K$ is an arbitrary index set (possibly infinite as noted in the comments), and it need not contain numbers like $1,\ldots,n$. However, given a sum
$$s_1+\cdots+s_n$$
with each $s_j\in\bigcup_{i\in K}S_i$, we can choose $i_j\in K$ such that $s_j\in S_{i_j}$. Here the $i_j$ need not be distinct. However we can group terms by letting $I=\{i_1,\ldots,i_n\}$ and writing the sum as
$$\sum_{i\in I}\Bigl(\sum_{i_j=i}s_j\Bigr)$$
where the outer sum is taken over the *distinct* values $i\in I$, and each inner sum is taken over all $1\le j\le n$ with $i_j=i$. Note each inner sum is an element of $S_i$ since $S_i$ is a subspace.